# Postfix discard not working properly

Tags: postfix

I have set up some bad phrases to look for inside the `body_checks` file. I'm not sure if I should post them here b/c of the nature of the words. An example of how I have it structured is like this:

```
/badword/    DISCARD
/anotherbadword/    DISCARD
/yetanotherbadword/    DISCARD
```

My version is:

```
mail_version = 2.10.1
```

I am seeing this in my maillog although none of these words match anything from my `body_checks` file.

```
discard: body <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 10px;">We understand that your time is valuable which is why we would love to reward you with 50 Reward Points for each verified review that you submit. It only from local; from=<support@myrealdomain.com>
```

This only seems to happen when the email contains this line of string but again none of these words are inside my `body_checks` file. Anyone else seen this happen before? If it is ok for me to post a link to my `body_checks` file plz let me know. I just didn't want to violate any policies here due to the nature of the words.

**Update**:

Ok, I finally figured out which phrase was the issue by searching the entire email and not just what was shown in the CLI maillog but I'm not sure why it was triggered.

Inside my email I have the word `click` and in my `body_checks` file I have the same word but without the the leading "c".

Is there a way to do an exact match to prevent this going forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to match actual words, instead of just random bits of text that might appear within a word, you should include [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) in your regular expression.

For example:

```
/man/ DISCARD
```

This will match both `man` and `humans`.

But use the word boundary to indicate that you want to match only a complete word.

```
/\bman\b/ DISCARD
```

Now this will match `man`, but not `humans`.

Comment: This worked perfectly Michael. Much appreciated bud!